# add character to particular column using awk

Tags: sed, awk, character, addition

I have a input file that I need to replace first character of column 3 (") with ("S)

**File1**:

```
1      2      "45554323"      p      b  
2      2      "34534567"      f      a  
3      3      "76546787"      u      b  
2      4      "56765435"      f      a
```

**Result**:

```
1      2      "S45554323"      p      b  
2      2      "S34534567"      f      a  
3      3      "S76546787"      u      b  
2      4      "S56765435"      f      a
```

I tried

```
awk '{gsub(substr($3,0,1),"\"S"); print}'
```

but it gives me `$3` with `S` at begin and the end, like `"S45554323"S`. Can you give me a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t"; } { sub( /[[:digit:]]/, "S", $3 ); print }' infile
```

That yields:

```
1       2       "S5554323"      p       b
2       2       "S4534567"      f       a
3       3       "S6546787"      u       b
2       4       "S6765435"      f       a
```

Or with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/\("\)[0-9]/\1S/' infile
```

Comment: @Birei.. thank you again :).. can you please tell me what is the meaming of [[:digit:]] .. i am rookie in awk

Comment: @mohammadreshad: It has the same meaning that `[0-9]` for an ASCII encoding.

Comment: dear Birei i have code like this NR=FNR'{a[$3]=$0;next;}{for(x in a){if(x==$5)print $1, $2, $3, $4, a[x];}}' but i want $4 print in the format that you said in your code but without using pipe .. iwant use your code in side my code! but it always print 1 idont know why

Comment: What are input files for that `awk` command? It seems a different problem, or at least not directly related with the answer to this question.

Comment: @Birei..my script is for combining columns of two files and put them to new file the result is something like this (1 1 2 "00301271" test 1 3) but i want combine my files and add "S" to column 4 also ("S00301271") i tried NR=FNR'{a[$3]=$0;next;}{for(x in a){if(x==$5)print $1, $2, $3,sub( /[[:digit:]]/, "S", $4) , a[x];}}' but it prints 1 for $4

Comment: I think the problem is that `sub` returns the number of substitutions. In this case only one. Execute the `sub` instruction just before the `print`, like: `sub( /[[:digit:]]/, "S", $4); print $1, $2, $3, $4 , a[x];`

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -naE '$F[2] =~ s/"/"S/; say join "\t", @F'
```

You might need to replace the tab `\t` with spaces if they are expected in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
awk '{sub(" \"","\"S"); print}' file
```

Result-1:

```
awk '{sub(" \"","\"S"); print}' file
1      2     "S45554323"      p      b  
2      2     "S34534567"      f      a  
3      3     "S76546787"      u      b  
2      4     "S56765435"      f      a
```

Result-2:

```
awk '{sub(" \".","\"S"); print}' file
1      2     "S5554323"      p      b  
2      2     "S4534567"      f      a  
3      3     "S6546787"      u      b  
2      4     "S6765435"      f      a
```